# How to set custom date ticks/breaks in plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to set custom ticks for specific dates on the x axis.
So far I've tried:

- setting the breaks on ggplot (however, after wrapping with ggplotly, breaks next to the edges disappear)
- setting the breaks on ggplotly in several ways (using tickmode array, rangebreaks, etc.) with no luck.
  Plotly documentation shows how to:
- set [custom ticks](https://plotly.com/r/tick-formatting/#tickmode--array), but not in date format
- work with [time series](https://plotly.com/r/time-series/), but not how to set custom breaks
- display [custom ticks at custom locations](https://plotly.com/r/axes/#enumerated-ticks-with-tickvals-and-ticktext), but I need labels to be the actual dates  of the required locations
- set `tick0` and `dtick` for regular custom ticks, though I need irregular ones

The closer I got to what I want was using the code shown below. However, the first tick I need won't show (the dates I want to use as breaks/ticks can be found in rangebreaks):

```
    df <- tibble(
  name = c("pat", "bill", "chuck", "dick", "ted"),
  uni = factor(c("DM", "DM", "DM", "VM", "VM")),
  cond =factor(c( "D", "E", "D", "E", "D")),
  f_des = as.Date(c( "2021-07-28", "2021-11-05", "2022-02-02", "2021-07-30", "2022-03-10")),
  f_ces = as.Date(c( "2021-11-04", "2022-01-15", "2022-04-10", "2022-03-10", "2022-04-10"))
)

#plot
ggplot(df, aes(fill = cond, text = name)) + 
  geom_rect(aes( xmin = f_des, xmax = f_ces,
                 ymin = as.numeric(uni) - .6 / 2, ymax = as.numeric(uni) + width / 2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(levels(df$uni)), labels = levels(df$uni), expand = c(0.01,0))

ggplotly(tooltip = c("text")) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list( 
    rangebreaks = list(values= c( "2021-07-30","2021-10-07","2021-11-05","2022-02-02")),
                       tickcolor="crimson", gridcolor="crimson"))
```

Here's the ouptut:
[plot screenshot with less ticks/grids than expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vTAd.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably more straightforward options but one option would be to first define your desired date breaks and convert them to proper `Date` objects.

For the `tickvals` convert the breaks to numerics, for the `ticktext` format the breaks in your desired format:

```r
library(plotly)

width <- .9

breaks <- as.Date(c("2021-07-30", "2021-10-07", "2021-11-05", "2022-02-02"))
ticktext <- format(breaks, "%b %d")
tickvals <- as.numeric(breaks)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(fill = cond, text = name)) +
  geom_rect(aes(
    xmin = f_des, xmax = f_ces,
    ymin = as.numeric(uni) - .6 / 2, ymax = as.numeric(uni) + width / 2
  )) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(levels(df$uni)), labels = levels(df$uni), expand = c(0.01, 0))

ggplotly(tooltip = c("text")) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(
    ticktext = ticktext,
    tickvals = tickvals,
    tickcolor = "crimson", 
    gridcolor = "crimson"
  ))
```

[image]